# Compact operators and projective tensor space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

I know that the space of all the bounded linear maps between two Banach spaces, denoted by $L(X,Y)$, has a relationship with the  projective tensor space of $X$ and $Y$,
$$({X \widehat\otimes_{\pi} Y})^* = L(X,Y^*).$$
Is there  any relationship between the space of all compacts operators between the two spaces, denoted by $K(X,Y)$, and the projective tensor space of $X$ and $Y$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the case of the Hilbert space $X=Y=\ell_2$, the space of compact operators on $X$ is a pre-dual of $X\otimes X$. The trace of these dualities on the space of diagonal operators is (isometrically) $c_0^*=\ell_1$ and $\ell_1^*=\ell_\infty$.

Comment: The duality $(X\otimes_\varepsilon Y)^* \cong X^* \otimes_\pi Y^*$ holds true, more generally, if one of the duals has the approximation property and one of the duals has the Radon-Nikodym property.

Comment: Ryan's book is a good source for starters https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-3903-4.